# Visual Studio Code list of keyboard shortcuts options

Tags: visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code is highly customizable in its key bindings, especially when it comes to contextual bindings (using `"when"` to bind the same shortcut to different commands in different contexts).

I'm looking for a **list of variables that can be used in those `"when"` conditions**. (There is a great [list of commands](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/keybindings), but conditions are not listed there). I see the condition is a JavaScript expression that must evaluate to a boolean, but it is unclear what variables are in scope.

Can someone provide such a list?

Comment: It's in the documentation now https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_advanced-customization

Comment: @NicolasGoy - your comment should be an accepted answer, thank you!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

These are hopefully all variables that can be used in `when` conditions:

```
editorFocus
editorHasMultipleSelections
editorHasSelection
editorLangId == 'name' // for example: editorLangId == 'typescript' 
editorTabMovesFocus
editorTextFocus
findWidgetVisible
globalMessageVisible
hasWordHighlights
inChangeAllMode
inDebugMode
inQuickOpen
inReferenceSearchEditor
inSnippetMode
markersNavigationVisible
parameterHintsVisible
peekDeclarationVisible
quickFixWidgetVisible
referenceSearchVisible
renameInputVisible
searchViewletVisible
suggestWidgetVisible
textCompareEditorVisible
```

You can concat them with `&&` and invert them with `!`. For example

```
editorTextFocus && !editorTabMovesFocus
```

Comment: Thank you @Wosi! Can you tell where you've got this list from? (Insight in the VSCode sources? Some link i'm missing? "Reverse-engineering" the default keyboard shortcuts?)

Comment: Go to `File -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts` in Visual Studio Code 0.9.1. The file you'll see contains all the defined shortcuts. I assume (optimistically) those `when` conditions cover all available variables.

Comment: Seems like parenthesis are not supported in the expression

Comment: `EditorLangId` sounds wonderful, to direct `ctrl-shiftr-I` (usually format) to different formatting tools for html, sass, ...

Comment: Downvoted – this list is terribly outdated. [mark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65997539/2072165) points to the docs, and is therefore self-updating and should (imo) be accepted.

Answer (score 17):

## Updated. April 2019 (version 1.34)

List of all variables that can be used in [when](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_when-clause-contexts) conditions in **version 1.34**:

```
acceptSuggestionOnEnter
accessibilityHelpWidgetVisible
activeEditor
activeEditorGroupEmpty
atEndOfWord
breadcrumbsActive
breadcrumbsPossible
breadcrumbsVisible
breakpointSelected
breakpointWidgetVisible
breakpointsFocused
callHierarchyVisible
commentEditorFocused
config.breadcrumbs.enabled
config.editor.stablePeek
config.editor.tabCompletion
config.emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab
config.gitlens.keymap
debugConfigurationType
debugState
debugType
dirtyDiffVisible
editorFocus
editorHasCallHierarchyProvider
editorHasCodeActionsProvider
editorHasCompletionItemProvider
editorHasDefinitionProvider
editorHasDocumentFormattingProvider
editorHasDocumentSelectionFormattingProvider
editorHasImplementationProvider
editorHasMultipleSelections
editorHasReferenceProvider
editorHasRenameProvider
editorHasSelection
editorHasSignatureHelpProvider
editorIsOpen
editorLangId
editorReadonly
editorTabMovesFocus
editorTextFocus
explorerResourceCut
explorerResourceIsFolder
explorerResourceIsRoot
explorerResourceMoveableToTrash
explorerResourceReadonly
explorerViewletFocus
explorerViewletVisible
expressionSelected
fileMatchFocus
fileMatchOrFolderMatchFocus
fileMatchOrMatchFocus
filesExplorerFocus
findInputFocussed
findWidgetVisible
firstMatchFocus
folderMatchFocus
gitlens:activeFileStatus
gitlens:canToggleCodeLens
gitlens:enabled
gitlens:key:,
gitlens:key:.
gitlens:key:escape
gitlens:key:left
gitlens:key:right
hasNextTabstop
hasOtherSuggestions
hasPrevTabstop
hasSearchResult
hasSnippetCompletions
hasWordHighlights
historyNavigationEnabled
historyNavigationWidget
inBreakpointWidget
inDebugMode
inDebugRepl
inEditorsPicker
inFilesPicker
inKeybindings
inKeybindingsSearch
inQuickOpen
inRecentFilesPicker
inReferenceSearchEditor
inSettingsEditor
inSettingsSearch
inSnippetMode
inViewsPicker
inZenMode
inputBoxFocus
inputFocus
interactivePlaygroundFocus
interfaceOverviewVisible
isDevelopment
isInDiffEditor
isInEmbeddedEditor
keybindingFocus
listFocus
listHasSelectionOrFocus
listSupportsMultiselect
markersNavigationVisible
matchFocus
messageVisible
multipleEditorGroups
notificationCenterVisible
notificationFocus
notificationToastsVisible
parameterHintsMultipleSignatures
parameterHintsVisible
problemFocus
problemsFilterFocus
problemsViewFocus
python.datascience.featureenabled
python.datascience.hascodecells
python.datascience.ownsSelection
reference-list.hasResult
referenceSearchTreeFocused
referenceSearchVisible
remoteFileDialogVisible
renameInputVisible
replaceActive
replaceInputBoxFocus
replaceInputFocussed
scmRepository
searchInputBoxFocus
searchViewletFocus
searchViewletVisible
settingsTocRowFocus
suggestWidgetMultipleSuggestions
suggestWidgetVisible
suggestionMakesTextEdit
supportedCodeAction
terminalFindWidgetFocused
terminalFindWidgetVisible
terminalFocus
terminalTextSelected
textCompareEditorVisible
textInputFocus
variablesFocused
watchExpressionsFocused
webviewFindWidgetVisible
workbench.explorer.openEditorsView.active
```

Comment: A link here would be nice as the list will no doubt change in the future.  Or did you just manually create this list from the shortcuts?

Answer (score 5):

The `when clause` documentation has been moved to [when clause contexts](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts).

But it is essentially the same info as was available before and does not provide much of a list of available contexts unfortunately.

Your best bet is to use the `Developer: Inspect Context Keys` command.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/65584576/836330 for more info on that command.

---

Intellisense for the `when` context is in v1.54, see [Intellisense for Context Keys](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_54.md#intellisense-for-context-keys) .  Although right now I have to trigger it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, the intellisense doesn't seem to pop up just by typing some letters:

[image: context key intellisense]

Comment: The documentation you linked now has an extensive-looking list of when-clause contexts in the "[Available contexts](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts#available-contexts)" section.