# Is there a master list / documentation for when clauses for vscode keybindings?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a master list / documentation for when clauses for vscode keybindings? *(this a question regarding the documentation of VS Code, not a request for a recommendation)*

I can not find this documented anywhere. If I wanted to specify a different action. Say I wanted to have `Ctrl`+`B` start a build task when not in a task 'context' and terminate when I am in a task context.

I went through the file and wrote down every when I could find, but nothing looked like 'the thing'.

```
// Place your key bindings in this file to overwrite the defaults
[{
    "key": "cmd+b",
    "command": "workbench.action.tasks.build",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
},{
    "key": "ctrl+c",
    "command": "workbench.action.tasks.terminate",
    "when": "???"
}
]
```

- inDebugMode
- inQuickOpen
- editorTextFocus
- suggestWidgetVisible
- suggestionSupportsAcceptOnKey
- editorLangId == 'xxx'
- searchViewletVisible
- renameInputVisible
- accessibilityHelpWidgetVisible
- quickFixWidgetVisible
- parameterHintsVisible
- referenceSearchVisible
- !config.editor.stablePeek
- markersNavigationVisible
- editorFocus
- inSnippetMode
- breakpointWidgetVisible
- findWidgetVisible
- editorTabMovesFocus
- editorHasSelection
- editorHasMultipleSelections
- inReferenceSearchEditor

(Also after writing this I found [this post where a similar list is posted, but there is no way to be sure that we have the entire list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33124104/377252)

Answer (score 4):

Although I'm sure it's not definitive, this is the list provided by Microsoft [.../when-clause-contexts](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts)

Comment: Thank you for this extremely useful answer. I have no idea why they say this is asking for a recommendation. This is official documentation of actual valid values in code. I found my personal value of `inSnippetMode` on the page you listed.