# Code scope depending "when" rules for keybindings?

Tags: visual-studio-code, key-bindings

i'm new in VSCode, but in Sublime Text it's possible to assign shortkeys with a code scope context, like:

```
{
        "keys": ["tab"],
        "command": "insert",
        "args":
        {
            "characters": "\n"
        },
        "context": [
            {
                "key": "selector",
                "operand": "source.css meta.rule.css meta.declaration-list.css",
                "operator": "equal",
                "match_all": true
            }]
    }
```

That means, when my cursor is at the scope `source.css meta.rule.css meta.declaration-list.css` and when I press `tab` key, I'll insert new line. Can I do like that in VSCode, because I try to search for the list of "when" rules, that's what I had found [Visual Studio Code list of keyboard shortcuts options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32987621/visual-studio-code-list-of-keyboard-shortcuts-options) and there is nothing about code scope context, or comparing current line text, or something like that.